# Почему не скрывается список?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста почему не проходит проверку когда элемент имеет header__lang--active

```
export default () => {
  const headerLang = document.querySelector('.header__lang');
  if (!headerLang) {
    return null;
  }
  function closeOptions() {
    headerLang.classList.remove('header__lang--active');
    window.removeEventListener('click', langListner, true);
    console.log('remover');
  }
  function openOptions() {
    headerLang.classList.add('header__lang--active');
    window.addEventListener('click', langListner, true);
    console.log('listner');
  }
  function langListner(e) {
    if (!e.target.closest('.header__lang')) {
      closeOptions();
      console.log('test');
    } else {
      closeOptions();
    }
  }
  headerLang.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!headerLang.classList.contains('header__lang--active')) {
      console.log(headerLang.classList.contains('header__lang--active'));
      openOptions();
    } else {
      console.log('firstListner-false');
      closeOptions();
    }
  }, true);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `addEventListener` на window третий параметр выставлен в значение `true` что перехватывает погружение события и таким образом сперва происходит клик по `window`, а потом уже по `.header__lang`.
Соответственно функция `langListner` попадает в `else` и удаляет класс `header__lang--active`, после чего отрабатывает клик по `.header__lang`, который опять добавляет этот класс, так как попадает в `if`.
Что бы это исправить нужно третий параметр выставить в `false`, но тогда класс `header__lang--active` не будет добавляться совсем, потому что теперь будет работать всплытие и клики отработают в обратном направлении. Что бы этого избежать в событии клика на `.header__lang` нужно запретить всплытие. Вот так:

```
headerLang.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.stopPropagation();
...
```